# I'm not sure if the HEAD of the local repository is at the latest point of the main branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm new to using Git and I'm not sure about the current situation.

[image]

At the moment, it is in the above state.
I've been able to "fetch" from a remote repository and open and run the latest state in my local VS Code, but does that mean that my local HEAD is at f52a6e9a at this point?

If so, I want to bring the local HEAD to the latest point of the main branch, but I don't know how.

---

2022/7/10/15: 06 Addendum
git switch main
After executing, the following status is displayed.
I think you can now move to the main branch, but at this point the HEAD is at f52a6e9a, right?

[image]

---

Then I executed "git checkout 17d73f6b63ca50e78d3a5a80339b6e8e037cc933".
Then, it became the following state.

[image]

This is what I want because HEAD is at the latest point of main branch.

As you may have noticed, this is something I'm doing experimentally to study git / Github, and I think I have a lot of basic things to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check your `git status` in a terminal (even from VSCode)

That will confirm where HEAD is.

A `git switch main` would be enough to bring your local repository to that local branch.
From there, a `git pull` would update it to `origin/main` if you want.

Avoid `git checkout`, which [is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).
And do not checkout a commit, which leads to [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

To go to  17d73f6 (the commit or `origin/main`):

```bash
git switch main
git pull
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The result of executing the git status command

Comment: On branch exp
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/exp'.

Comment: I believe VonC meant 'git checkout main' not switch

Comment: Does this mean "I'm in the exp branch at the moment"?

In the remote repository, the exp branch has already been merged into the main branch and deleted.

Comment: @Gec Why using the old obsolete checkout command? It is [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), to switch to a branch. Or `git restore`, to restore file. Not `git checkout` [which is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

Comment: @森口万太郎 Yes, you are on exp. `git switch main` will make you go to your expected commit.

Comment: I added the situation after that to the question.
I will investigate the necessary matters based on the answers I received.
Thank you for staying with us so far.

Comment: @森口万太郎 Forget `git checkout`. And a checkout of a commit will leave you in a [detached HEAD state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309). Which is not what you want. Do a `git switch main` again, then `git pull`: you will then be at 17d1.

Comment: @VonC yes. I stand corrected. Haven't updated git in a long while and I did try the switch before I posted, only to get "git: 'switch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'." Thanks!

Comment: @Gec: This means you have an old version of Git (pre-2.23).